# How can I show xib directly in xcode enviroment?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, development-environment, xib

I've been reading articles at [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) and saw that they show an XIB being edited in Xcode directly:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCTSF.jpg

How can do this in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is new version of xcode just download & install it :) u will have same editor in it :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a new feature of XCode 4 and onwards. If you have the Apple Developer Membership, you can download it at http://developer.apple.com/xcode/.